# What is the function of this opamp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, zener

Hello ladies and gentleman,

I'm trying to figure out how this circuit works :
[image: unknown circuit]

I was thinking it is a kind of charge controler where Rx is the load.
Any help would be pleased

Comment: Is this a MOSFET on the right side? HOW high is VCC?

Comment: Yes it is a MOSFET. How the value of VCC impact the behavior of the circuit ?

Comment: If this is a MOSFET, then R1 makes no sense. If VCC is lower then 2.5V, then the zener diode will not conduct. This would change the operation of the circuit significantly.

Comment: It seems your are right it could be a bipolar. It could be a mistake !

Comment: If you are looking for a further expanation, then i) get the circuit right and ii) explain what you found out by yourself and where you need help.

Comment: IF this uses a P Channel MOSFET it is much more "conventional" than the alternative as R2 is in the source lead - and the opamp polarity is correct. Note that opamp output and input must be able to handle the voltages used - many opamps will not drive or sense close to V+. Best is a RIRO - rail in rail out opamp

Answer (score 2):

It's a constant current source. A fixed voltage (2.5V) across a fixed resistance (R<sub>2</sub>) gives a fixed current.

Comment: It seems your are right it could be a bipolar. It could be a mistake ! Is there a limit value for the load ?

Comment: It's a JFET. The limit is whatever the supply can handle.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's intended to be a current source, but someone wired the opamp input backwards.

Assume the opamp inputs are flipped.  The circuit tries to keep the voltage across R2 the same as the zener voltage.  That means the current will be the Vz/R2.  The only place this current can go is thru the load, Rx.

To see how this works, let's say for example that the voltage across R2 is a bit less than the zener voltage.  That means the + input is higher than the - input (remember, flipped from what you show).  That makes the opamp output voltage go up, which makes the FET conduct more and raise the load voltage, which causes the load to presumably draw more current, which then causes a larger voltage drop across R2.

Comment: I think the source (p ch) is connected to R2 Olin.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, if it's a P channel device, then the opamp inputs have the correct polarity as shown.